# On Mac OS X, easy_install fabric and/or easy_install pycrypto fails due to linker error "illegal text-relocation"

Tags: python, macos, fabric, pycrypto

When trying to `easy_install`[`fabric`](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.5/) (or `easy_install`[`pycrypto`](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/), which fabric depends on), I got the following linker error on Mac OS X:

```
ld: illegal text-relocation to ___gmp_binvert_limb_table in /usr/local/lib/libgmp.a(mp_minv_tab.o) from ___gmpn_divexact_1 in /usr/local/lib/libgmp.a(dive_1.o) for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was using a custom install of python, which apparently wasn't compatible with my standard install of [libGMP](http://gmplib.org/).  Building libGMP from source (in my own prefix location, used by my special python install) fixed the problem.

```
$ bunzip2 gmp-5.0.5.tar.bz2
$ tar -xf gmp-5.0.5.tar
$ cd gmp-5.0.5
$ ./configure --prefix=/path/to/my/special/prefix
$ make
$ make check
$ make install
$ easy_install pycrypto
$ easy_install fabric
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks! I had "illegal text-relocation to ___gmp_binvert_limb_table" issues as well while doing `pip install fabric`. Small (probably obvious) note that the --prefix option to ./configure is... optional. The ./configure will work just as well without.

Comment: Oddly enough, my solution was kind of the opposite: `brew unlink gmp` --after that I could successfully `sudo pip install pycrypto`