# Mac easy_install clang warnings lead to failure

Tags: python, macos, installation, clang

I'm trying to install module for python on Mac. I use easy_install to install scp, ssh, but it fails.

```
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mno-fused-madd'
src/_fastmath.c:1545:20: warning: comparison of unsigned expression < 0 is always false [-Wtautological-compare]
                    else if (result < 0)
                             ~~~~~~ ^ ~
src/_fastmath.c:1621:20: warning: comparison of unsigned expression < 0 is always false [-Wtautological-compare]
                    else if (result < 0)
                             ~~~~~~ ^ ~
2 warnings generated.
src/_fastmath.c:83:13: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'Py_ssize_t' (aka 'long') to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
            size = p->ob_size;
                 ~ ~~~^~~~~~~
src/_fastmath.c:86:10: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'Py_ssize_t' (aka 'long') to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
            size = -p->ob_size;
                 ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~
src/_fastmath.c:1310:12: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'unsigned int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
            offset = mpz_get_ui (mpz_offset);
                   ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/gmp.h:890:20: note: expanded from macro 'mpz_get_ui'
#define mpz_get_ui __gmpz_get_ui
               ^
src/_fastmath.c:1360:10: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
            return return_val;
            ~~~~~~ ^~~~~~~~~~
src/_fastmath.c:1373:27: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
            rounds = mpz_get_ui (n) - 2;
                   ~ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
src/_fastmath.c:1433:9: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
    return return_val;
    ~~~~~~ ^~~~~~~~~~
src/_fastmath.c:1545:20: warning: comparison of unsigned expression < 0 is always false [-Wtautological-compare]
                    else if (result < 0)
                             ~~~~~~ ^ ~
src/_fastmath.c:1621:20: warning: comparison of unsigned expression < 0 is always false [-Wtautological-compare]
                    else if (result < 0)
                             ~~~~~~ ^ ~
8 warnings generated.
ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/local/lib/libgmp.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (i386): /usr/local/lib/libgmp.a
ld: illegal text-relocation to ___gmp_binvert_limb_table in /usr/local/lib/libgmp.a(mp_minv_tab.o) from ___gmpn_divexact_1 in /usr/local/lib/libgmp.a(dive_1.o) for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
```

I'm considering that it might be the 32/64 problem but i'm not sure. And the clang is version 4.1. I need to install modules on python, are there any better ways than easy_install?

Comment: Check out this question with the same problem in another package. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13937228/on-mac-os-x-easy-install-fabric-and-or-easy-install-pycrypto-fails-due-to-linke