# installing paramiko > pycrypto gives compile error

Tags: paramiko

I'm not a C programer. Any ideas what this needs?

Here's the install commands I've tried:

```
pip install paramiko
sudo pip install paramiko
```

Output:

```
src/_fastmath.c:1545:20: warning: comparison of unsigned expression < 0 is always false [-Wtautological-compare]

                        else if (result < 0)

                                 ~~~~~~ ^ ~

src/_fastmath.c:1621:20: warning: comparison of unsigned expression < 0 is always false [-Wtautological-compare]

                        else if (result < 0)

                                 ~~~~~~ ^ ~

2 warnings generated.

clang -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup build/temp.macosx-10.8-x86_64-2.7/src/_fastmath.o -lgmp -o build/lib.macosx-10.8-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/PublicKey/_fastmath.so

ld: illegal text-relocation to ___gmp_binvert_limb_table in /usr/local/lib/libgmp.a(mp_minv_tab.o) from ___gmpn_divexact_1 in /usr/local/lib/libgmp.a(dive_1.o) for architecture x86_64

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------

Command /Users/Ceti/.pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.7.3/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/private/tmp/pip-build-root/pycrypto/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-Rrbho6-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-build-root/pycrypto

Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Ceti/.pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.3.1-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 139, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Users/Ceti/.pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.3.1-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 271, in run
    requirement_set.install(install_options, global_options, root=options.root_path)
  File "/Users/Ceti/.pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.3.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py", line 1185, in install
    requirement.install(install_options, global_options, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/Ceti/.pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.3.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py", line 592, in install
    cwd=self.source_dir, filter_stdout=self._filter_install, show_stdout=False)
  File "/Users/Ceti/.pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.3.1-py2.7.egg/pip/util.py", line 662, in call_subprocess
    % (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd))
InstallationError: Command /Users/Ceti/.pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.7.3/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/private/tmp/pip-build-root/pycrypto/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-Rrbho6-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-build-root/pycrypto
```

Comment: glad you got it working.  you should post what you did as an answer, then other people who see this will know what worked (i deleted my answer since it wasn't correct).  also, you can mark your own answer as correct after a few days, which improves your record and makes people more likely to answer questions you ask.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13937228/on-mac-os-x-easy-install-fabric-and-or-easy-install-pycrypto-fails-due-to-linke

try it!

Answer (score 7):

In CentOS/RHEL 6 "yum install python-devel" will fix this problem. (You need the Python headers so pycrypto can be installed.)

Answer (score 4):

Somehow this is a top google result even though the question is horrible and no solution was presented. For my setup I am installing paramiko on debian 7 and python 2.7.

I fixed this issue for myself by installing python-dev:

```
aptitude install python-dev
```

I hope that helps anyone else that comes across this error message.